# Python Recursion not exiting the function, Find the last index of 'x' in the 'arr' recursively

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, infinite-recursion

### Read input as specified in the question

### Print output as specified in the question.

```py
arr=[34, 57, 82, 41, 65, 35, 82, 27, 36, 12, 6, 40, 66, 99, 25, 29, 22, 25, 12, 24, 65, 15, 5, 43, 28, 33, 76, 32, 13, 95, 22, 84, 71, 23, 28, 7, 65, 94, 18, 47, 9, 42, 61, 73]
x=61
si = 0
def lastIndex(arr, x, si):
    arrLen = len(arr)
    lastKnownIndex = -1
    if (arrLen == 0):
        return lastKnownIndex
    if (si == arrLen):
        if (arr[si] == x):
            lastKnownIndex = si
        return lastKnownIndex
    if (arr[si] == x):
        lastKnownIndex = si
    lastIndex(arr, x, si + 1)
    return lastKnownIndex

print(lastIndex(arr, x, si))
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an infinite recursion but an `IndexError` exception.  The problem comes from these two lines:

```py
    if (si == arrLen):
        if (arr[si] == x):
```

The second line will always raise an exception since if `si == arrLen` then `arr[si]` is equivalent to `arr[len(arr)]` which is always wrong (remember that list items are indexed from `0` to `len(arr) - 1`).

Here is a patched version that fixes this bug and simplifies a bit your code:

```py
arr=[34, 57, 82, 41, 65, 35, 82, 27, 36, 12, 6, 40, 66, 99, 25, 29, 22, 25, 12, 24, 65, 15, 5, 43, 28, 33, 76, 32, 13, 95, 22, 84, 71, 23, 28, 7, 65, 94, 18, 47, 9, 42, 61, 73]
def lastIndex(arr, x, si=0):
    #  empty list or end of list reached
    if si >= len(arr):
        return -1
    #  x is at position si
    if arr[si] == x:
        return si
    #  owtherwise look at next position
    return lastIndex(arr, x, si + 1)

print(lastIndex(arr, 61))  #  print 42
```